# Error when adding WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

when i try add WebBrowser component to form, IDE write error (Value does not fall within the expected range). Both case in VS2005 and VS2008. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding it manually, i.e. creating the control in C# code, and then try to run it, so you can debug it and see where exactly the exception is thrown.